# Forzar click en botón de reproducción de iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un iframe con un video de youtube y lo que quiero es que se reproduzca el video al cargar la pagina.
Lo que quiero hacer es forzar el click en el botón de reproducir sin tener que usar el autoplay.

```
window.onload = function() {
$(".ytp-large-play-button ").get(0).click();
};
```

intente hacerlo asi, pero no encuentra la clase, que podría hacer ahí?

Gracias

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es simular un click, https://victorroblesweb.es/2015/05/12/simular-clicks-con-jquery/
en esa pagina podras incontrar la informacion

Comment: si, ya lo intente pero es que lo pasa es que no me encuentra la clase del bton que esta dentro del iframe

Comment: deverias de utilizar getElementById() para mandar a llamar el id, o en su caso manda a llamar la clase getElementByClassName()